# Recording/retrieving input events with irregular frequency

Tags: c#

Just as a toy, I'm using the iTunes SDK and XNA to make my own quasi-GuitarHero game. The actual libraries aren't important, so I didn't tag them. This question is about a data structure.

Basically I want to start playing a song, and allow the user to play guitar to the song, recording in memory the Red/Yellow/Green/Blue/Orange key presses, as well as the strum, to play back later.

I've tried several different techniques, the most accurate being a bitwise `int[]` array where each element represents a 10ms time slot (and each bit of each int represents a physical key) once as an offset from the song start. This seems inefficient however, as I have to pigeonhole keypresses into these 10ms slots, not to mention a huge array size for a several minute song.

Any suggestions for a better way to implement this? My goal is to then serialize this data structure to disk for retrieval later. The overall goal of this project is to use this data to control LEDs in some fashion to a song, FWIW.

Thanks!

Comment: You might need someone with music/mathematical knowledge to help? 10ms seems too short for a gap between 2 notes, but I'm not an expert. :)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head o.k.w., 10ms is way too short, but anything smaller in that would yield an impractically ginormous array!

Comment: if 10ms is way too short, shouldn't you try larger value like 50ms instead of something smaller?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your comment. Yes, Xms>50ms>10ms is ideal, however I feel that conceptually my design is flawed, and so "pidegon-holing" time slices using that method feels the wrong way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the key up and key down events in a log format with a timestamp (relative to the start of the file) at the appropriate precision. You could use a List together with a custom class for storing details of the event type (which key, and up or down) and the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, Mark.

I have tried this method, it worked as well as any other. The challenge I face with this, is how to retrieve the played keys when re-playing the song. How would I ensure each replayed key plays at its exact logged time during playback?

I'm trying to avoid constantly constantly checking the playtime of the currently playing song. How do you think the Guitar Hero programmers implemented this?

Comment: Without knowing a little more about how your application is implemented, it is hard for me to be precise, but I am assuming that your application uses asynchronous calls and is event based. You can have a class that parses the file and reads the next line. It checks how long must pass before the next keypress and schedules an event at that time. When you handle the event you will also need to schedule the next event. I don't know how the GH programmers did it - not very well though because there's at least one bug in GH3 where the music doesn't play even if you hit the note at the right time.

Comment: "It checks how long must pass before the next keypress and schedules an event at that time." This is getting closer and closer to what I'm trying to achieve. How can I schedule an event to fire at a certain time, or X milliseconds after an asynchronous call, assuming function calls will be near instantaneous.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I guess that the reason why you want to store the keypresses is so that you can a) display the correct graphics on the screen and b) check if the player pressed the button at the right time. In both these cases it is simpler. For a) you can use the Paint event and read all the events from now and +1 second. For b) You need to check the distance to the nearest event. Neither of these scenarios require you to generate an event yourself. So it might be simpler than I first suggested.

Comment: Wow, the comments are getting far more 'fatter' than the answer, haha. Might want to consider revising the answer? :)